# HQL Same table selection seems to override column with the latest value

Tags: sql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, h2

I'am facing an issue with a native sql script in hibernate for testing, i'am loading data into a h2 database from a csv...

well the problem is when i do  :

```
Select t1.name, t2.name FROM Person as t1, Person as t2  where t1.name='TOTO' and t2.name!='TITI'
```

I got the correct values, unless t1.name seems to be replaced by t2.name.

PS : the same script is working fine in SQLDevelopper.

Any clue or help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the aliases are being confused because they are the same.  Try using `as`:

```
Select t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2
FROM Person t1, Person t2 
where t1.name = 'TOTO' and t2.name <> 'TITI';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help i tried the aliases, didn't work. I suspect hibernate because i disconnected it from H2 and i am now testing directly on the Oracle Database and still having the same issue.

Comment: @Sifmon . . . I removed the `as`.  Oracle does not allow those in the `from` clause.  Ironically, I only used them because they were in your original query; I think the use of `as` in the `from` clause just clutters queries.

Comment: Query is not realy the issue, the real query is more complicated than the one given just for example. I still suspecting Hibernate but i have no clue why Hibernate is acting like that. Just for a reminder the same query is working well if executed from SQLDeveloper...

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and provide examples of where the query works and doesn't work.